# Cannot call method 'click' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement a jQuery 'slide toggle'. At the top of the page (in the header) I have included:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Then the code of the area is:

```
<a href="#" id="morebutton" class="more">More</a>
<div class="toggler">
<div id="morepanel" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
  <p>Text</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="js/toggle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The toggle.js contains:

```
$('#morebutton').click(function () {
$('#morepanel').slideToggle('slow', function () {
    // Animation complete.
});
});
```

When I click it I get the error:

> Toggle.js:1Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of undefined.

I can't at all figure out what to do. The divs are nested within further divs, and content holders, etc, but I can't see why this would be an issue.

Comment: Are you running the script in the head element? Then you need to wrap it in a `ready()` event

Answer (score 4):

You should wrap your code in a `$(function() {});` statement. This will make sure it will execute **after the DOM loads**.

Currently, your code is being executed before the DOM is fully built, resulting in a reference to a DOM-element that does not yet exist.

Example:

```
$(function() {
    $('#morebutton').click(function () {
        $('#morepanel').slideToggle('slow', function () {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have wrapped it with this, and although I am sure this takes me one step closer to getting it working as it no longer errors, it also no longer hits any breakpoints and still appears to do nothing. Any further suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

[Hotlinking is disabled for files on the jQuery site](http://blog.jquery.it/2010/12/30/hotlinking-to-be-disabled-on-jan-31-2011/). The file won't load, so jQuery won't be loaded.

Use [one of the CDNs instead](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery).

E.g.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's good to know, thanks. I've replaced it, but it appears to be one of many problems and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is probably not loaded at this point. Wrap your call as such:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#morebutton').click(function () {
    $('#morepanel').slideToggle('slow', function () {
        // Animation complete.
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: I get the problem 'toggle.js:1Uncaught TypeError: Obkect #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready'. If I just write '$(function() {' then it picks it up, though now it doesn't error, nor work.

Comment: That would sound very much like it's not loading JQuery or there is a conflict;  you're not using Prototype or any other javascript framework are you ?

Comment: No, that is the only JQuery on the page. There isn't even much other javascript. Certainly nothing that uses a $.

Comment: What's the result of typing $ or jQuery in the js console on the browser? If it's undefined, you definitely haven't loaded jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that '#morebutton' isn't actually selecting anything.

Have you tried put a breakpoint on with Firebug or the IE/Chrome equivalents and run the selector from the Console ?

Comment: Although as Aron says, this may be because the script is running before the DOM has loaded!

Comment: After using Aron's suggestion, it no longer hits the breakpoints I have set.